# Internet Explorer- Div tags to display tabular data with headers are not scrollable

Tags: css

My code contains 3 div elements to display tabular data. Parent div act as container. First div child display header data and second child displays row data.I want to display horizontal scroll bar in parent div columns are more and second child display vertical scroll bar, it can scroll only data and not table header(headers are sticky)

when i scorll horizontally it should scroll headers and data but when i scroll vertically it should scroll table data not headers

Comment: my problem is when i scorll horizontally it should scroll headers and data but when i scroll vertically it should scroll table data not headers

Answer (score 0):

```
.parent { overflow-x: scroll; } .child { overflow-y: scroll; }
```

How about this?

Comment: your solution not works. my problem is when i scorll horizontally it should scroll headers and data but when i scroll vertically it should scroll table data not headers

Comment: i  didn't get u what ur saying i am new to this forum

Comment: Gl to anybody trying to answer this question without any code provided whatsoever.